# What is meant by Computed column? can we modify it?

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, pnp-powershell, spfield

I am working on a client SharePoint online tenant, and they have a column of type Computed, as follow:-

[image]

where users' submit answers from a Power app and the field will either show Passed or Failed.. here is the field property:-

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $columns = Get-PnPField -List "C-19 Self-Assessment App"
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> foreach($column in $columns){
>>
>> if($column.InternalName -eq 'LinkTitle')
>> {
>>     Write-Host "Column Title  :" $column.Title
>>     Write-Host "Description   :" $column.Description
>>     Write-Host "Group Name    :" $column.Group
>>     Write-Host "Internal Name :" $column.InternalName
>>     Write-Host "Static Name   :" $column.StaticName
>>     Write-Host "Scope         :" $column.Scope
>>     Write-Host "Type          :" $column.TypeDisplayName
>>     Write-Host "Schema XML    :" $column.SchemaXml
>>     Write-Host "Is Required?  :" $column.Required
>>     Write-Host "Is read only? :" $column.ReadOnlyField
>>     Write-Host "Unique?       :" $column.EnforceUniqueValues
>>     Write-Host "Sealed?       :" $column.Sealed
>>
>>
>>
>>
>> }
>>
>> }
Column Title  : Result
Description   :
Group Name    : Custom Columns
Internal Name : LinkTitle
Static Name   : LinkTitle
Scope         : /sites/HomeOffice/en-ca/Forms/Lists/C19 SelfAssessment App
Type          : Computed
Schema XML    : <Field ID="{82642ec8-ef9b-478f-acf9-31f7d45fbc31}" ReadOnly="TRUE" Type="Computed" Name="LinkTitle" DisplayName="Result" DisplayNameSrcField="Title" ClassInfo="Menu" AuthoringInfo="(linked to item with edit menu)" ListItemMenuAllowed="Required" LinkToItemAllowed="Prohibited" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="LinkTitle" FromBaseType="TRUE" CustomFormatter="{&quot;elmType&quot;:&quot;div&quot;,&quot;style&quot;:{&quot;box-sizing&quot;:&quot;border-box&quot;,&quot;padding&quot;:&quot;0 2px&quot;},&quot;attributes&quot;:{&quot;class&quot;:{&quot;operator&quot;:&quot;:&quot;,&quot;operands&quot;:[{&quot;operator&quot;:&quot;==&quot;,&quot;operands&quot;:[&quot;[$Results]&quot;,&quot;Failed&quot;]},&quot;sp-css-backgroundColor-blockingBackground50&quot;,&quot;&quot;]}},&quot;children&quot;:[{&quot;elmType&quot;:&quot;span&quot;,&quot;style&quot;:{&quot;line-height&quot;:&quot;16px&quot;,&quot;height&quot;:&quot;14px&quot;},&quot;attributes&quot;:{&quot;iconName&quot;:{&quot;operator&quot;:&quot;:&quot;,&quot;operands&quot;:[{&quot;operator&quot;:&quot;==&quot;,&quot;operands&quot;:[&quot;[$Results]&quot;,&quot;Failed&quot;]},&quot;ErrorBadge&quot;,&quot;&quot;]}}},{&quot;elmType&quot;:&quot;span&quot;,&quot;style&quot;:{&quot;overflow&quot;:&quot;hidden&quot;,&quot;text-overflow&quot;:&quot;ellipsis&quot;,&quot;padding&quot;:&quot;0 3px&quot;},&quot;txtContent&quot;:&quot;[$Title]&quot;,&quot;attributes&quot;:{&quot;class&quot;:{&quot;operator&quot;:&quot;:&quot;,&quot;operands&quot;:[{&quot;operator&quot;:&quot;==&quot;,&quot;operands&quot;:[&quot;[$Results]&quot;,&quot;Failed&quot;]},&quot;&quot;,&quot;&quot;]}}}],&quot;templateId&quot;:&quot;ConditionalColumn&quot;}" Version="3"><FieldRefs><FieldRef Name="Title" /><FieldRef Name="LinkTitleNoMenu" /><FieldRef Name="_EditMenuTableStart2" /><FieldRef Name="_EditMenuTableEnd" /></FieldRefs><DisplayPattern><FieldSwitch><Expr><GetVar Name="FreeForm" /></Expr><Case Value="TRUE"><Field Name="LinkTitleNoMenu" /></Case><Default><HTML><![CDATA[<div class="ms-vb itx" onmouseover="OnItem(this)" CTXName="ctx]]></HTML><Field Name="_EditMenuTableStart2" /><HTML><![CDATA[">]]></HTML><Field Name="LinkTitleNoMenu" /><HTML><![CDATA[</div>]]></HTML><HTML><![CDATA[<div class="s4-ctx" onmouseover="OnChildItem(this.parentNode); return false;">]]></HTML><HTML><![CDATA[<span>&nbsp;</span>]]></HTML><HTML><![CDATA[<a onfocus="OnChildItem(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;" onclick="PopMenuFromChevron(event); return false;" href="javascript:;" title="Open Menu"></a>]]></HTML><HTML><![CDATA[<span>&nbsp;</span>]]></HTML><HTML><![CDATA[</div>]]></HTML></Default></FieldSwitch></DisplayPattern></Field>
Is Required?  : False
Is read only? : True
Unique?       : False
Sealed?       : False
```

now i want to modify how the field show/calcualte Passed and Failed... so how i can do so?
Thanks

Comment: Hi John John, I wonder why they need a computed column for handling this info as all the logic if the field could (and should?) be handled in the power app. But if they really must handle it in the field I believe you must update the schema XML. Its not visible from your screen shot, so hard to tell what is going on. So you could copy and paste the xml here and we can take a look. But again, I would recommend to handle this logic in the Power App :)

Answer (score 0):

Computed columns are similar to calculated columns, but they are used only for rendering data in the view and do not store any actual data in fields value.

To modify how field is rendered you should change Column formatting JSON. You may also need to change field schema XML  of the field to specify referenced columns of the computed property.